# How can I `find()` data with deep query in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The data in the MongoDB is like this:

First record:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b309244e138235684843b5d"),
    "branch_id": 3,
    "group": 2,
    "rule_id": 60001,
    "details": {
        "detail_list": [
            {
                "count": 36072
            },
            {
                "count": 12035
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Second record:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b309244e134567684843b5d"),
    "branch_id": 9,
    "group": 9,
    "rule_id": 60001,
    "details": {
        "detail_list": [
            {
                "count": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to get the records whose `count > 0`, which means I want to get the first record and filter out the second record. How can I implement that?

I have tried `db.events.find({'details':{'detail_list':{'$in':[{'count':{ '$gt': 0 }}]}}})`, but it doesn't work. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's basic [Dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) syntax:

```
db.events.find({"details.detail_list.count": {"$gt": 0}})
```

Comment: As he mentioned, detail_list as an array of count,if first count is zero and and second one is greater than zero,is your query work?

Comment: @MohammadRaheem  

Good question. Let me have a try.

Comment: Yes, it returns documents with at least 1 sub-document with count > 0: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Answer (score 0):

$in is not required in the above mentioned case, use the right traversing path to get the desired result

```
db.events.find({"details.detail_list.count":{"$gt": 0}})
```